# Wocommerce breadcrumb separator - How to use image instead of symbole

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, breadcrumbs

this is the snippet i'm using right now to replace the default symbole

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'wcc_change_breadcrumb_delimiter', 20 );
function wcc_change_breadcrumb_delimiter( $defaults )
    
{
    $defaults['delimiter'] = ' &gt; ';
    return $defaults;
}
```

&gt is the entitie for > so the goal is to replace it by an image file using something like  echo ' ? somewhere somehow :D

Thanks a lot in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can use `image` tag check the below code.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'wcc_change_breadcrumb_delimiter', 20 );
function wcc_change_breadcrumb_delimiter( $defaults ){
    $defaults['delimiter'] = '<img src="https://cdn.iconscout.com/icon/free/png-16/right-arrow-1438234-1216195.png">';
    return $defaults;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code put in your active theme functions.php file

As delimiter set span tag and set background image for that span tag.

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_breadcrumb_defaults', 'wcc_change_breadcrumb_delimiter' );
function wcc_change_breadcrumb_delimiter( $defaults ) {
    $defaults['delimiter'] = ' <span></span> ';
    return $defaults;
}
```

And give css like

```
nav.woocommerce-breadcrumb span {
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-image: url(arrow.png); //give your image path
    display: inline-block;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
}
```